# Dealing with different API layout

Tags: android, xml, api, layout

How can I set a different xml layout file for each Android version? like what you do for the strings, you make a folder called values-es and there will be the strings for spanish version, is there a way to do that with xml layouts?

Comment: Are you talking about different screen sizes, or different API versions, or different languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create different folders for each version like this(for example):

`layout-v11` - this layout folder will be used when the API version is Honeycomb or above

(replace `11` with the android version you want to create layouts for other versions).

See this link for more information -> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources